# MacOS install Python package error with stdlibc++

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to install the following Python package on my MacOS https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy , unfortunately it is not working.

From what I understand I should switch to std=libc++, I have no idea how to do it though.

```
>>> python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing cvxpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to cvxpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to cvxpy.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to cvxpy.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'cvxpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'cvxpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_cvxcore' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g - fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -Icvxpy/cvxcore/src/ -Icvxpy/cvxcore/python/ -Icvxpy/cvxcore/include/Eigen -I/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -I/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c cvxpy/cvxcore/src/cvxcore.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/cvxpy/cvxcore/src/cvxcore.o
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the
  command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
  [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
In file included from cvxpy/cvxcore/src/cvxcore.cpp:15:
cvxpy/cvxcore/src/cvxcore.hpp:18:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
     ^~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: try opening setup.py and insert `-std=libc++` right after `gcc`. don't forget to put a space in between them.

Comment: `gcc -std=libc++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreach...`

Comment: There is no gcc in the setup.py file